# Quickhelp for Python in Emacs autocomplete.el?

Tags: python, emacs

I am using Emacs 23.1.1 on GNU/Linux with autocomplete.el 1.3 and Ropemacs 0.6.

In Lisp programming, autocomplete.el shows the documentation (known as 'QuickHelp' in autocomplete.el) of the suggested completions. Python completion with ropemacs works, but does not show quick help for the Python completion. Is it possible to enable it and did somebody make it work?

Comment: How did you get python completion with ropemacs working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ropemacs does the job : Use the function `rope-show-doc` over the symbol or use the keybinding `C-c d`. Simple :)

Comment: Is not really using autocomplete but this does the job, thanks and +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using all the autocomplete stuff in all my developing environments. They rarely do what I want. Either the lists is too long, or too short, or not sorted well. Therefore I use **dabbrev-expand** in all my modes **global-set-key** to **tab**.

This works even quote well for text. Usually it is enough to get a good expansion from the local buffer where you are in. If I start typing in an empty buffer I open a second one which *expand* can use to look up its suggestions. This is not language sensitive, not does depend on the object you want to call a method of, but its still a big boost, and you get used to it. Maybe its not, you don't get "quick help" this way.